# Method causes OutOfMemory error

Tags: unity, gameobject, recursion

If a GameObject in my game has a special ability it triggers it, but I want all the special GameObjects that this GameObject affects to also trigger their abilities, for example if a bomb hits some objects, if these objects are also bombs, trigger them too. I though this would be easy by calling the method that handles all the special abilities recursively, but, as always, it wasn't. Basically what happened is a chain reaction of bullcrap that caused Unity to show an OurOfMemory error. Also makes my PC freeze completely while politely turning all the screens off.

The question is, how can I make it so it triggers all the affected cubes' special abilities, without everything going nuts?

Code:

```
     //Triggers the cube's special ability, if it has any
    private void TriggerSpecialCubeAbility(GameObject specialCube) {
        switch (specialCube.tag) {

            //Destroy all cubes in a radius from the special cube
            case "Bomb":
                TriggerBombAbility(specialCube);
                break;

            //Destroy all cubes of the same color as the special cube
            case "Lighting":
                TriggerLightingAbility(specialCube);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private void TriggerBombAbility(GameObject specialCube) {
        var nearbyColliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(specialCube.transform.position, explosionRadius);
        Instantiate(particles[0], specialCube.transform.position, specialCube.transform.rotation);
        Instantiate(particles[1], specialCube.transform.position, specialCube.transform.rotation);

        foreach (var collider in nearbyColliders) {
            if (collider.tag == "Indestructible")
                return;

            var affectedCube = collider.gameObject;
            TriggerSpecialCubeAbility(affectedCube);
            Destroy(affectedCube);
        }

        destroySelectedCubes = true;
        //          Physics2D.gravity *= -1;
        //          Physics.gravity *= -1;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice. You can edit your existing question if you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you seem to have a bug in `TriggerBombAbility()`: that `return` should be a `continue`.

Now a quick way to fix your issue of infinite recursion is to devise a way to mark a `GameObject` as no longer triggerable. For instance you could have a `hasBeenTriggered` boolean, defaulting to false, and you set it to true before triggering abilities:

```
       case "Bomb":
            specialCube.hasBeenTriggered = true;
            TriggerBombAbility(specialCube);
            break;
```

Then you only call `TriggerSpecialCubeAbility()` if the ability hasn’t already been triggered:

```
        var affectedCube = collider.gameObject;
        if (!affectedCube.hasBeenTriggered)
        {
            TriggerSpecialCubeAbility(affectedCube);
            Destroy(affectedCube);
        }
```

<s>Alternatively, you could put that check in `TriggerSpecialCubeAbility()` itself and do an early exit:</s> Nevermind; this would require a check around `Destroy()`, too, and is therefore more complicated.

Comment: hasBeenTriggered doesn't exist for game objects in Unity though. Is there a reason why you put the bool as a member of GameObject?

Comment: @Milen because `TriggerSpecialCubeAbility` uses a `GameObject`; I have no knowledge of how Unity classes can be extended, so I suppose you could create a `CubeGameObject` class, add `hasBeenTriggered` there,  and change the `TriggerSpecialCubeAbility` prototype, which would be more type-safe.